How to use a single DTO class in .NET 8.0 instead of multiple DTOs for various endpoints
In my .NET Core application, assume I have 10 API endpoints and each endpoint has a DTO. Now I need to consolidate this 10 endpoints into 1 endpoint with http GET method. How to merge all 10 DTOs into a single, common DTO?
Plan is to call the actual methods from this 1 endpoint method based on type value.
Please suggest a method to use a common DTO. Also whether from client side I need to send all the properties in the common DTO or only the required fields that was passed earlier.

Are you passing all your dtos as json in the request body?  System.text.json support polymorphism by using a $type-property, so that seem like the simplest option. But it might not be a great idea to merge a bunch of unrelated types into the same type hierarchy.

Why not make all your DTOs share a common base type with any common properties they have, then you don't have to repeat that stuff in each DTO.

Do not do this.  This is an anti-pattern.  It is ridiculously difficult to unit test.  Documentation will become a pain in the rear for you.  Making changes to code for one DTO is likely to break stuff for other DTOs.  It may be okay to consolidate endpoints that return the same DTO (such as search functions) but otherwise what you are proposing is not going to be very maintainable code in the long run.

you can use generics.
each endpoint could have their object and that object covered a standart request object.
public record ApiRequest<T>
{
  public T Data { get; set; }
  public string Token { get; set; }
}

public record InvoiceRequest
{
  public string No { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

ApiRequest<InvoiceRequest>() request = GetRequest();

request.UserId
request.Data.No
request.Data.Date



